# Standardization of an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to standardize a numpy array of shape(M, N) so that its column mean is 0. I think I have used the formula of standardization correctly where x is the random variable and z is the standardized version of x.

> z = (x - mean(x)) / std(x)

But the column mean of the resulted array is not 0. They are very small number but not zero. Any insight regarding my misunderstanding or mistake is welcome. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.load('data/filename.npy').astype('float')
XNormed = (X - np.mean(X, axis=0))/np.std(X, axis=0)
column_mean = np.mean(XNormed, axis=0)
print(column_mean)
```

Comment: try casting the number as an int, it should floor itself

Comment: Yeah. I know that. But I want to know why this does not work. Because it should not depend on datatype or rounding problem. Should it?

Comment: This is an artifact of working with floating point numbers.  If you need more precision, use the type `np.float64`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try this. :)

Answer (score 8):

Your code is correct but as you mentioned in the formula of your own question you need to divide by the standard deviation and not by the range of the data (as in your code). The line below , which uses numpy's std() should correct it:

```
XNormed = (X - X.mean())/(X.std())
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying things and forgot to change it back before posting. Updated the code.  I used standard deviation only to calculate XNormed.

Comment: Please note that this will *not* perform standardization as you would like to have for example in the case with regularization. You need to specify that you would like to normalize for each column (np.mean(X, axis=0) and np.std(X, axis=0).